# Loop function in R

Tags: r, for-loop, time-series, arima

I am trying to use Auto Arima function for 70 variables. For it I need to create time series 70 times.

```
dealer1 <- ts(tier2[,2], start=c(2015,8), end = c(2018,12), frequency=12)
dealer2 <- ts(tier2[,3], start=c(2015,8), end = c(2018,12), frequency=12)
dealer3 <- ts(tier2[,4], start=c(2015,8), end = c(2018,12), frequency=12)..and so on.
```

And then I need to use the Auto Arima function again for 70 variables.

```
automatic.dealer1 = auto.arima(dealer1, ic = "aicc")
automatic.dealer2 = auto.arima(dealer2, ic = "aicc")
automatic.dealer3 = auto.arima(dealer3, ic = "aicc")... and so on
```

And then forecast the output:

```
forecast.dealer1 = forecast(automatic.dealer1, h = 3)$mean
forecast.dealer2 = forecast(automatic.dealer2, h = 3)$mean
forecast.dealer3 = forecast(automatic.dealer3, h = 3)$mean
```

I am trying to use the for loop in R, but I am getting an error.
What am I doing wrong??

```
k <- 1
l <- 2

   for(i in seq(1,70)){

      dealer[k] <- ts(dealer1[,l], start=c(2015,8), end = c(2018,12), frequency=12)

      dealer[k]

      automatic <- auto.arima(dealer.[k], ic = "aicc")

      foreArima <- forecast(automatic, h=3)

      automatic

      foreArima

      k <- k+1
      l <- l+1
}
```

I need the ARIMA model selected for all the 70 variables I have in my data plus the forecast for each one of them to be displayed

Data sample looks like:

[image]

Comment: could you please share the `tier2` dataframe with us. you can use `dput` or something [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

this helps in answering the question

Comment: There are several typos in your for-loop. It should start like: `for(i in seq(1,70)){` also it looks like you're trying to print a value `dealer.[k]` it should probably be `dealer.k[k]`

Comment: furthering from @dylanjm response. the dealer should be dealer.k[i] or some variable name indexed by your index. The first line inside the loop should also be indexed, or it will overwrite every time

Comment: Edited the code in the question above, and in R as well. but still the loop function is giving me an error.

Comment: I need the loop to run till the last column and display the ARIMA model selected for each and every dealer. And also the forecast for each model

Answer (score 0):

first of all you don't need a loop to create a `ts` object. 
You can create a multivariate `ts` object like this

```
myts <- ts(tier2[,2:70], , start=c(2015,8), frequency=12)
```

Here is how you use a for loop in R:

```
result <- numeric(ncol(myts)) #initialize a vector where the results will be stored.

for (j in 1:ncol(myts)) {
    automatic.dealer <- auto.arima(myts[,j], ic = "aicc")
    result[j] <- forecast(automatic.dealer, h = 3)$mean
}
```

Just as additional information: most of time you can avoid loops in R using `apply`, `sapply` or `lapply`. Doing so increases readability of your code and the performance.

**EDIT**: if you want to save all the results as well you can store the results from `auto.arima` into a list:

```
result <- numeric(ncol(myts))
arima.list <- list()
forecast.list <- list()

for (j in 1:ncol(myts)) {
    automatic.dealer <- auto.arima(myts[,j], ic = "aicc")
    arima.list[[j]] <- automatic.dealer
    forecast.list[[j]] <- forecast(automatic.dealer, h = 3)
    result[j] <- forecast.list[[j]]$mean
}
```

Comment: I am trying to run the code that gives me the forecast model for each and every dealer, so 70 models output and then also the forecast of each model/ dealer

Comment: Still getting an error, error displayed:::::Error in auto.arima(myts[, j], ic = "aicc") : 
  No suitable ARIMA model found
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In is.constant(x) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In is.constant(x) : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In value[[3L]](cond) :
  The chosen seasonal unit root test encountered an error when testing for the first difference. 0 seasonal differences will be used. Consider using a different unit root test.
4: In is.constant(x) : NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: This means that on one of your columns no ARIMA model could be fit. 
You can include a `print(j)` in your loop to find the index of this column

Comment: Nope, still getting the same error. Including Print function in the loop did not give me the index which is causing that error. Am I overwriting Dealer in the above query.. I do not wanna write 70 codes for 70 dealers.. :(